# Smooth function of infinitely many variables

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, smooth-functions, frechet-derivative

Consider $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, the set of real-valued sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, as a mere set. Let $f : \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function, and suppose that $f$ is smooth whenever we vary only finitely many arguments at a time.

> Does it follow that $f$ only depends on finitely many arguments? In other words, is there a finite subset $F \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and smooth $g : \mathbb{R}^F \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
> $$ f = g \circ \pi,$$
> where $\pi : \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^F$ is the projection?

My suspicion is that the answer is yes, and that a proof may be possible by first showing the following weaker conjecture:

> At every point of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, only finitely many partial derivatives of $f$ are nonzero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer with a different mechanism than the (nice) answers involving limits.

Let $j(x) = \lfloor |x|\rfloor +2$, and let $g(x) = x^2(1-x)^2$. Define $f\colon\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}\to\Bbb R$ by
$$
f(x_1,x_2,\dots) = g\big( x_1-\lfloor x_1\rfloor \big) x_{j(x_1)}.
$$
Varying $x_1$ chooses which of the other variables is relevant to the value of $f$; the function $g$ ensures that the handoff from one $x_j$ to the next happens in a differentiable way. For greater smoothness, change $g(x)$ to $x^9(1-x)^9$ or to some nonconstant $C^\infty$ function that vanishes outside $(0,1)$.

Comment: Of course! Beautiful, simple and interesting example. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you :) By the way, it's usually a good idea to wait some time (at least 24 hours) before accepting an answer, just to give people time to post and perhaps provide even better responses to your question.

Comment: Just in case you're curious: for some background on my (embarrassingly elementary) question and on how your answer has been helpful, see [this n-Category Café discussion](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2020/01/codensity_monads.html#c057715).

Answer (score 3):

Define $f$ as $(x_n) \mapsto \lim_n x_n$ if $(x_n)$ converges, and $(x_n) \mapsto 0$ otherwise. Then $f$ is smooth, even constant, whenever you vary only finitely many indices (since this does not affect convergence or the value of the limit). But the value of $f$ does not depend only on finitely many indices (as the limits themselves do not).

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x) = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \tan^{-1}(x_n)$. This is smooth (indeed constant) when restricted to finitely many variables, but it clearly does not factor through any finite $F$.